# Rendering to custom FrameBuffer using same texture both as input and output

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, framebuffer, render-to-texture

Some Fragment shaders in ShaderToy (e.g. fluid dynamics, https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tGfDW ) use same buffer as both input and output. But when I try to do this in my C/C++ code it does not work (I renders strange checkerboard artifacts like inconsistent visual memory). To workaround this issue I have to use two different FrameBuffers A,B and flip textures ( first render A to B then render B back to A )

I understand that OpenGL does not allow to use the same texture both as input and output (?) due to memory consistency issues.
But isn't there more elegant solution than using two FrameBuffers ? E.g. using some lock, or temporary cache (I don't know some sychronization flag which takes care of this)???

**EDIT - Details to answer the comment/question:**

> OpenGL (depending the GL version) has some very specific rules of what
> can and can''t be done when the same texture is used as render target
> and sampler input. If your use case can be implemented within this set
> of requirements or not is not clear, as you have not explained what
> exactly you need or want to do here.

basically I want to implement Fluid-Dynamics solver (e.g. that from ShaderToy linked above) as well as other partial differential equation solvers. That means each pixel output depends on some convolution mask (derivative, laplacian, average) of neighboring pixels. There may be also some movement (advection) which means reading values form distant pixels.

Currently I realized the artifacts appear mostly when I read/write pixels which are different place - i.e. it is non-local (e.g. pixel[100,100] depend on pixel[10,10])

**Example of simple Fluid-Solver from Shadertoy:**

```
vec4 solveFluid(sampler2D smp, vec2 uv, vec2 w, float time, vec3 mouse, vec3 lastMouse)
{
    const float K = 0.2;
    const float v = 0.55;
    
    vec4 data = textureLod(smp, uv, 0.0);
    vec4 tr = textureLod(smp, uv + vec2(w.x , 0), 0.0);
    vec4 tl = textureLod(smp, uv - vec2(w.x , 0), 0.0);
    vec4 tu = textureLod(smp, uv + vec2(0 , w.y), 0.0);
    vec4 td = textureLod(smp, uv - vec2(0 , w.y), 0.0);
    
    vec3 dx = (tr.xyz - tl.xyz)*0.5;
    vec3 dy = (tu.xyz - td.xyz)*0.5;
    vec2 densDif = vec2(dx.z ,dy.z);
    
    data.z -= dt*dot(vec3(densDif, dx.x + dy.y) ,data.xyz); //density
    vec2 laplacian = tu.xy + td.xy + tr.xy + tl.xy - 4.0*data.xy;
    vec2 viscForce = vec2(v)*laplacian;
    data.xyw = textureLod(smp, uv - dt*data.xy*w, 0.).xyw; //advection
    
    vec2 newForce = vec2(0);
    data.xy += dt*(viscForce.xy - K/dt*densDif + newForce); //update velocity
    data.xy = max(vec2(0), abs(data.xy)-1e-4)*sign(data.xy); //linear velocity decay
    
    #ifdef USE_VORTICITY_CONFINEMENT
    data.w = (tr.y - tl.y - tu.x + td.x);
    vec2 vort = vec2(abs(tu.w) - abs(td.w), abs(tl.w) - abs(tr.w));
    vort *= VORTICITY_AMOUNT/length(vort + 1e-9)*data.w;
    data.xy += vort;
    #endif
    
    data.y *= smoothstep(.5,.48,abs(uv.y-0.5)); //Boundaries
    
    data = clamp(data, vec4(vec2(-10), 0.5 , -10.), vec4(vec2(10), 3.0 , 10.));
    
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Possibly [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) (`gl_LastFragData`)

Comment: OpenGL (depending the GL version)  has some very specific rules of what can and can''t be done when the same texture is used as render target and sampler input. If your use case can be implemented within this set of requirements or not is not clear, as you have not explained what exactly you need or want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I realized the artifacts appear mostly when I read/write pixels which are different place - i.e. it is non-local (e.g. pixel[100,100] depend on pixel[10,10])

Yes, this is never going to work on GPUs, as there are no particular guarantees on the order of individual fragment shader invocations whatsoever. So if the invocation writing to pixel `[100,100]` will see the results of the invocation writing to `[10,10]` or the original data will be totally random. As per the spec, you're getting undefined values when reading in such a cuncurrent read/write scenario, so theoretically, you could get even not one or the other, but see partial writes or totally different values (although that's not likely to occur on real world hardware).

And any order guarantees of such a scale simply does not make sense within the render pipeline, so there is also no partical means of synchronization you can manually add to solve this issue.

> To workaround this issue I have to use two different FrameBuffers A,B and flip textures ( first render A to B then render B back to A )

Yes, the ping-pong approach is what you should do for this use case. And honestly, it should not incur any significant performance penalty in that scenario anyway, as you seem to write to each output pixel once anyway, so you don't need an additional copy of "untouched" pixels. So all it costs is the additional memory.

Comment: thanks. Yes, it does not add performance cost (if I split even and odd frames) but it adds some complexity to the program